# Why has Ubuntu 13.10 more recent packages than 13.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, ruby, testing

I don't understand how some packages are managed in Ubuntu. How are they moved from unstable to testing?

The [Debian FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-choosing.html) says:

> - **Unstable** has the most recent (latest) versions. But the packages in unstable are not well tested and might have bugs
> - **Stable** contains old versions of packages. But this package is well tested
> - **Testing** falls between these two extremes

At the moment I'm running Raring 13.04 (unstable). Saucy 13.10 (testing) has more recent packages, which breaks this rule.

**Solution**

Ubuntu's version management is not the same as Debian's one: It's **development** which then becomes, gets merged into, **stable**.

The current state of Ubuntu is:

- Ubuntu Raring 13.04 is **stable**
- Ubuntu Saucy 13.10 is **development**

So it's all normal to have more recent packages in Saucy. See answers for more details.

Misunderstanding solved ;)

---

Extension

Well, now I understood raring is stable and saucy development (now is shifted to "saucy --> trusty" as well), how can this situation be explained regarding the 'virtualbox' package:

> - raring (4.2.10-dfsg-0ubuntu2.1)
> - saucy (4.2.16-dfsg-3)
> - virtualbox (4.3.0-89960~Ubuntu~raring)

Here, raring provides newer than saucy, which fits Ubuntu's workflow.

But VirtualBox provides newest to stable Ubuntu versions, instead of the development one.

Since the Ubuntu development version is intended to be merged as a stable Ubuntu in the end, it doesn't make sense for VirtualBox to provide for stable and not for development.

Any input about that ?

Comment: Why do you quote the Debian FAQ while you are using Ubuntu? Why do you think 13.10 is testing and 13.04 is unstable? Please hit the **edit** link and the information.

Comment: @MadMike It's done by now. I kept the initial content, in case someone else goes through the same misunderstanding and condusion between Debian and Ubuntu releases models.

Comment: [The reason hello gets filtered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I've edited your question to make it easier to read. Fell free to edit back or some further as you wish. The original version can be retrieved in the edit history.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I get it now: once a solution is adopted, it's better to edit the initial question to sum it up and bring the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Ubuntu follows much of Debian's package management guidelines, and indeed many Ubuntu packages come without modification from Debian, there is a different cycle. The packages in different Ubuntu versions do not map directly to particular Debian sections. One of the motivations for Ubuntu was a desire to have more frequently releases than Debian, which necessarily involves a different structure.

There is no `stable`, `testing` and `unstable`. There is always one development release, and several currently-supported short-term and long-term releases. Once a release is made, the package versions are generally not changed, and updated for bug and security fixes, not for new features.

In debian, there is a single unstable release (`sid`), which in theory can be continually updated forever (expect lots of things to break). In Ubuntu, a new development release is started immediately after the previous release. This is populated with a mixture of packages, mostly from Debian testing/unstable along with a number of Ubuntu specific ones. There is then a 6-month cycle during which bugs are fixed and integration between packages tested. The versions of packages to be included in the release are fixed some time before the release is made to give time for testing. Finally, the development version becomes the new release, and the cycle repeats.

You can read about the [Ubuntu release process here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess).

Comment: Thanks you all for answers. chronitis' one is very clear.  
  
I indeed confused the Ubuntu versions management into the Debian one. After reading how you explained it to me, I get this understanding now:  

Packages merges in Debian: unstable --> testing --> stable  
Packages merges in Ubuntu: development --> stable --> LTS

Understood that all Ubuntu's stable releases are not held as LTS releases.

Comment: No, it's development --> stable, where stable may independently be LTS or non-LTS. Packages from a stable version do not migrate to another stable version, be it LTS or not

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu =/= Debian. The fact that Ubuntu is based on Debian, and the fact that Ubuntu takes packages from Debian's testing, imply no relationship between them, including package management and package compatibility.

Raring and Saucy are different distributions, with different repositories, and different versions of the packages. 
[For example](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice), Raring has Libreoffice 4.0, and will always have it until its End Of Life, while Saucy has 4.1, and will always have it.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to distinuish the difference between the Debian and Ubuntu package landing workflows here. I think you've conflated these and that this is the cause of your confusion.

Debian has unstable and testing. Ubuntu does not.

Debian's unstable is always called sid. Debian's testing is currently called jessie (which will be the name of the next stable release when it's ready).

Ubuntu's "Raring" 13.04 is the latest stable release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu's "Saucy" will be 13.10, is the development release and is expected to be released today (at which point it will replace Raring as the latest stable release).

Ubuntu does have a rough equivalent of Debian's unstable->testing flow. In Ubuntu, we call it proposed migration, documented here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ProposedMigration. In Ubuntu's case, we have a roughly analogous saucy-proposed->saucy flow, where "saucy" represents the name of the development release and thus changes every release.

Comment: It seems Ubuntu has some real "testing" releases finally ;) ubuntu.com/info/testing . Anyway, those seem to be private deliveries to Ubuntu contributors, not public software releases.

Comment: No, they are public. Example: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2013-September/002548.html